# Type error when generating a Geometric distribution (python 3)

Tags: python, random

I'm creating a class for my personal RNG, but when doing this implementation for the Geometrical one, I keep getting the error :    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'method' and 'float' but I cannot find where it is wrong, neither using the documentation for "floor", where I think is the issue.

```
class mi_rng:
        def __init__ (self, seed=0):
            self.seed= 0
            self.m= 2**32
            self.a= 1664525
            self.c= 1013904223
            self.normal_stored= None
    def geometrica2(self, p):
            return int(floor(log(self.uniforme/log(1.0-p))))
    muestra= [rng.geometrica2(0.7) for _ in range(1000)]
    print("Geometrica 2, media: ", mean(muestra), ", varianza: ", var(muestra))
```

Comment: Is `self.uniforme` supposed to be a function? If so, maybe you need `self.uniforme()`?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you the problem is with your division operation `/`.

what is `self.uniforme`?

Is it a function to generate a uniform(e)?  if so try:  `self.uniforme()`

Comment: Lord, that's true! What a silly mistake. Though now I get ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer. Uniforme is indeed a function to generate a Uniform, but in Spanish, sorry I forgot to change that.

Comment: I would suggest as a troubleshooting technique to break up the "big fat math problem" you have rolled into that return statement into separate lines.  Much easier to debug.  And you can experiment with them in interpreter easier.  I suspect you are trying to take log of a negative number

Comment: It seems to be sort of that problem. Using only de Log part, gives invalid value, but I dont understant, for uniforme is + and so is 1-p (I'm using 0.7 to test it)